# Python code freeze on different pc

Tags: python, numpy, hardware

I got a Neural Network implemented with numpy (Python 2.7) and a machine to test it faster. Lately my code on this machine got freeze but if a test it on my notebook (less cpu, ram, etc) it run without problem (only slower).

Which can be the problem? I thought that it was my code but if it works on a slower pc, so I think that machine have a trouble.

edit: Also, sometimes it works without problems.

edit 2: Both pcs are Ubuntu 16.04

edit 3: It happens event with same input and parameters

Comment: windows? linux? which python version, distribution? you can use anaconda to set up the same python env in both PCs...

Comment: Both pcs have Ubuntu 16.04, python 2.7.

Comment: Where in the code does it freeze?

Comment: is the input the same when it freezes and when it doesn't? what is the bottleneck in your system and in your program? try log the cpu, ram and swap usage (total and python) from an other shell in each second while running. look into system logs. is there enough space on partitions? run your code with smaller input data and under a profiler.

Comment: Yes, it's exactly same

Comment: how can i check swap usage of python?

Answer (score 1):

If it doesn't always occurs and is confined to one machine it could very well be a hardware problem.

The problem is that they are often hard to test, because they generally leave little evidence in the way of log files.

- Try testing the RAM.
- If that doesn't turn up errors, try logging the CPU temperatures to check that it doesn't get too hot.
- Also, log the different voltages. It could be that the power supply is on the way out.

Comment: with htop i saw that it doesn't use even 1/4 of ram.

Comment: About CPU temperatures, with lm-sensors ( http://askubuntu.com/questions/15832/how-do-i-get-the-cpu-temperature ) it doesn't get over 40°C

Comment: I don't get the last one :(

Comment: `lm-sensors` should ba able to monitor the different voltages used in the PC, provided the PC has the right hardware.

Answer (score 1):

**Try compiling code on the same machine where your code gets frozen**. Each machine (more precisely microprocessor) has different instruction set. The flaws in instruction set may be covered by using Microcode. This could be the place where the problem may exist.

Comment: I use this machine with different codes, by the moment it only got this problem with this :/